# How to target only 2nd, 3rd, 4th item in a Woocommerce cart?

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I just want to be able to show the different item names (with gravity view shortcode) in them based on if the item is the first, second, third etc in the cart.

This works if one item, and only shows the 1 item name (gravity view shortcode); but if there are 2 or more items in the cart then both item names (gravity view shortcodes) show for both items.

I'm self taught so it's probably something stupid I'm missing?

```
// Display a custom text under cart item name in cart page

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'name_on_cart_item', 10, 1 );

function name_on_cart_item( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

  if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >=  2)
        return; 

    // Initialising
  $count = 0;

    // Iterating though each cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {  
        $count++;
     if( 1 == $count){ // First item only 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_text_cart_item_name_r', 9, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
function custom_text_cart_item_name_r( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

        $item_name = '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1471'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$item_name;
   
    return $item_name;


}  }
 else if( 2 == $count ){ // Second item only 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_text_cart_item_name_2', 9, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
function custom_text_cart_item_name_2( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

        $item_name = '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1569'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$item_name;
   
    return $item_name;


}  
}}
}
```

Comment: $count = 0 instead of $count == 0;

Comment: No :( that didn't work

Comment: Ok, that is just the first correction to make. Can you elaborate more on your question?

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping! If I have 1 item in my cart, I want the product name that shows to be: $item_name = '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1471'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$item_name;           but if I add a second item, I want the first to still show the above, but then the second items name must be $item_name = '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1569'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$item_name;

Comment: So you mean just the different gravity view id for the second product? What if someone adds 2 items to the cart and then deletes the first one?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean. The flow they follow means they most likely won't delete products once added --- it is an onboarding form where we add the product based on their answers in a gravity form.

Comment: Why don't you store the ID of gravity form in the cart item when adding it to the cart and then retrieve when displaying. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47868328/11656450) can help

Comment: @RobynCameron Ok but this confuses me again. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that when the second item  is added it adds both gravity view to both items. I want only one, and which one depending on if its the first or second item in the cart

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the library/framework you're using so my answer is based-on the logic I am able to see on the code.

If you only want to get a single item name, then you don't need the for loop, you can pass the index of the item you want to the `function name_on_cart_item( $cart, $index )`:

```
function name_on_cart_item( $cart, $index ) {

    // assuming that $cart is a key value pair
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_text_cart_item_name', 9, 3 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
    function custom_text_cart_item_name( $cart, $index) 
    {
        // assuming that the item name is at this key $cart[$index]['name']
        return '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1471'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$cart[$index]['name'];
    }
}
```

A solution for getting a single item and all items:

```
// to get a single item
function name_on_cart_item( $cart, $index ) {

    // assuming that $cart is a key value pair array
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_text_cart_item_name', 9, 3 ); 
    // would be a good idea to also pass 9, 3 or any other variable you would want as a dynamic value into the name_on_cart_item function
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'do_shortcode', 11 );
    function custom_text_cart_item_name( $cart, $index) 
    {
        // assuming that the item name is at this key $cart[$index]['name']
        return '<div class="item-shipping-class">' . __(" [gravityview id='1471'] ", "woocommerce") . '</div>' .$cart[$index]['name'];
    }
}

// to get all items
function all_items_names()
{
    $count = 0;
    $items = '';

    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count ($cart); $i++) 
    {
        // since there is a function already defined for getting a single item, we can call the function and append to the results to $items string
        $items .= name_on_cart_item ($cart[$i], $i);
    }

    return $items;
}
```

The idea is to pass the $cart into the function then get the values from that array than to rely on checking the $count (the drawback with checking the count each time means you will have to know the size of the cart to implement all the if statements). I hope this helps in pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much! 

For a little more context - the possible if results will at the moment only be max 2 items added to the cart - they are subscription products. In future that would probably increase to max 5 - the item gets added through a funneled user journey.

Comment: Alright, then to pass the index as part of the parameters would do the trick. The 1st element index will always be at 0, and 2nd item index will be 1. So the my example above to get the 1st item name_on_cart_item($cart, 0), name_on_cart_item($cart, 1) for the second item

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your time - I did try your solution but it doesn't seem to to work - no errors but it doesn't insert the gravity view at all (without editing re passing index as part of the parameters)

Comment: can you try print_r($cart) before add_filter() functions and show me the array